# Compiling AggregatorV2V3Interface leads to TypeError: Interfaces cannot inherit. interface

Tags: solidity

I have added a file MockV3Aggregator.sol under contract->test to deploy a mock. However, when I use "brownie compile" I get the following errors:

```
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

C:/Users/hp/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol:7:38: TypeError: Interfaces cannot inherit.
interface AggregatorV2V3Interface is AggregatorInterface, AggregatorV3Interface
                                     ^-----------------^

C:/Users/hp/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol:7:59: TypeError: Interfaces cannot inherit.
interface AggregatorV2V3Interface is AggregatorInterface, AggregatorV3Interface
                                                          ^-------------------^
```

Any way can this be fixed?

Comment: Why are you inheriting interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to these problem. Here is this [link](https://githubhelp.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/issues/7).

Basically, you need to import AggregatorInterface.sol and AggregatorV3Interface.sol into your MockV3Aggregator.sol

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorInterface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

and inherited these two interfaces in the MockV3Aggregator contract declaration.

```
contract MockV3Aggregator is AggregatorInterface, AggregatorV3Interface {...}
```

Replacing these will solve the problem